# Making up a string from second string, order of characters

Tags: c++

Basically I need to check if the characters found in second string can make the first string. The program works, however I have this problem that it doesn't take the character order in mind.

For example if I input:

`UMC UniverseCeeMake ==> Yes`

but it should input No because UMC != UCM, how can I make it check the character order aswell? can someone assist?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 256;

bool canMakeStr2(string str1, string str2)
{

    int count[MAX] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
        count[str1[i]]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++)
    {
        if (count[str2[i]] == 0)
           return false;
        count[str2[i]]--;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{   
    int n;
    string str1;
    string str2;

    cin>>n;
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> str1 >> str2;
        if(str1.length()<=10000 && str2.length()<=10000)
          if (canMakeStr2(str2, str1))
       cout << "Yes";
    else
       cout << "No";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot implement this using a (multi)set (or an `int[256]` effectively being used as one). In fact using a set here makes this more complicated than necessary. Just start at the start of both strings and then find repeately try to find the next char in the target string in the source string starting at the current position in the source string. If at any point you cannot find the char in the source string, the output needs to be "No", if not, the output should be "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

As Fabian has alread stated. You approach with counting letters will not work. You will never cover the sequence.

You need to select a different approach. The most easy one is to use the `std::string`s existing `find` function.

So, you will go over all characters in the given character set in the correct sequence with a simple range based `for` loop. Then you can use the `find` function to check, if the character is existing in the other string.

To ensure the sequence, you must not search always from the beginning, but from the last poasition (+1) where a character was found. This will keep the ensure the sequence.

Example:

UMC UniverseCeeMake

- Search for the 'U' starting from the beginning
- 'U' Found at position 0. Increment start position to 1
- Search for 'M' staring from position 1
- 'M' found at position 11 (already behind the 'C'). Increment start position to 12
- Search for a 'C' starting at position 12
- Cannot be found --> Result will be "No"

This can be implemented very easyly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool canMakeStr(std::string toBeChecked, std::string characterSet) {

    // Result of function. We assume that it will work
    bool result{ true };

    // position, where we find a charcted in the string to be checked
    size_t position{};

    // Go through all characters from the given character set
    for (const char c : characterSet) {

        // Look, where this character has been found
        position = toBeChecked.find(c, position);

        // If we could not find the character in the string to be checked
        if (position == std::string::npos) {

            // Then the result is false
            result = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            // Character was found. Now, we implement the solution to check for the sequence
            // We will not start to search again at the beginning, but after the just found character
            // This will ensure that we keep the sequence
            ++position;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    // Read the number of test cases
    unsigned int numberOfTestCases;  std::cin >> numberOfTestCases;

    // Work on all test cases
    while (numberOfTestCases--) {

        // Read the 2 strings
        std::string characterSet, toBeChecked;  std::cin >> characterSet >> toBeChecked;

        // And check for the result
        if (canMakeStr(toBeChecked, characterSet))
                std::cout << "Yes\n";
            else
                std::cout << "No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```